# Map sorted by value

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, dictionary, dataset

I have this now, but I get problems when keys clash (which i fix by adding a very small number to the double. But this does not work very well (and I really don't want to add the small number)

```
 TreeMap<Double, String> statisticAndTitle = new TreeMap<Double, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

The string is unique, so if i have:

- D 1.1
- B 2.0
- C 4.0
- A 1.1
- E 3.3

I want it sorted as D1 A1 B2 E3 C4 (Order of appearance (NOT alphabetical) in the list is important, if D1 is before A1 in the list, it should also be so in the map ( this means I can't just sort the second column with a normal sorting algorithm since it does not take into account the place in the list)

Any ideas on how to implement with a map, or other way?

Comment: Sounds like you really want a `TreeMap<Double, List<String>>`, or maybe a Guava `TreeMultimap<Double, String>`.  You can't have duplicate keys with a Java `Map`.

Comment: A `TreeMap` isn't your best solution when you have keys that are exactly the same. Have you considered using an `ArrayList` filled with objects of a class that contains both your `double` and `String`? Afterwards you can create a custom comparator which first sorts on number and in case the numbers are the same sorts on String.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I don't want to sort on String, but on place in the list. You gave me some ideas though. Why would putting them in a HashMap and then into an ArrayList be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it sorted as D1 A1 B2 E3 C4 (Order of appearance (NOT alphabetical) in the list is important.

A List maintains the order.

Create a class that holds the String letter and Double number.  Implement Comparable and write the compareTo method in the class.

Create and load a List of class.

Sort the List.

Comment: thx for "A List maintains the order." it guided me into Collections.sort() which is what helped me. "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort."

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinkedHashMap`. It remembers the order of addition.